# JQuery UI Tabs close widget button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I know that JQuery UI Tabs has a close feature for individual tabs. Is there a way to add a button onto the widget to close it?

Comment: Relevant: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: I guess, more relevant as it's an example that appears to do exactly what you want: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation

Comment: If you mean close the whole tabs container, you can still add your custom button, either out of the tabs div or inside it, and use jQuery's `hide()` on the div, or `tabs('destroy')` depending if you want to be able to show it again or completely destroy it..

Comment: None of those examples on jqueryui.com close the widget, just individual tabs.  Even worse, closing a lone tab, leaves the widget there tabless, like a fish out of water...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who want this.

```
<div id='tabs'><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close">close</span>

.ui-icon-close{
    cursor:pointer !important;
    float: right;
}
```

[image]